# How to add an object according to a variable?

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.4

I was wondering how would I add "thing" (name of object) onto the screen each time the "dodged" (score) increases by 1? So I would want the number of "things" to be equal to the "dodged" + 1 (when the score is 0, the number of things is 1, when the score is 1 the number of things is 2, etc.).
Here is the full code, I'm creating code based off of sentdex's "Game Development in Python 3 With Pygame" series on youtube:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

crash_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("Crash.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.load("BackgroundMusic.wav")

display_width = 1200
display_height = 1000
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (200,0,0)
bright_red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0,200,0)
bright_green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0,0,255)
grey = (146, 159, 138)

car_width = 148
car_height = 200

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Racing game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImage = pygame.image.load("Car.png")
carIcon = pygame.image.load("caricon.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(carIcon)

pause = False

def things_dodged(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render("Dodged: " + str(count), True, black)
    gameDisplay.blit(text, (0, 0))

def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImage, (x,y))

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), (display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    game_loop()

def crash():
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(crash_sound)
    
    message_display("You crashed!")

def button(msg, x, y, w, h, ic, ac, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x, y, w, h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()
            
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic, (x, y, w, h))

    if 900 + 100 > mouse[0] > 900 and 800 + 50 > mouse[1] > 800:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, bright_red, (900, 800, 100, 50))
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, (900, 800, 100, 50))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ((x + (w/2)), (y + (h/2)))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def unpause():
    global pause

    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
    
    pause = False

def paused():

    pygame.mixer.music.pause()

    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), (display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (149, 799), (249, 799), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (250, 800), (250, 850), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (250, 850), (150, 850), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (149, 850), (149, 800), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (899, 799), (999, 799), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (1000, 800), (1000, 850), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (1000, 850), (900, 850), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (899, 850), (899, 800), 1)

        button("Continue", 150, 800, 100, 50, green, bright_green, unpause)
        button("Quit", 900, 800, 100, 50, red, bright_red, quitgame)
        
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Racing game", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), (display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (149, 799), (249, 799), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (250, 800), (250, 850), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (250, 850), (150, 850), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (149, 850), (149, 800), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (899, 799), (999, 799), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (1000, 800), (1000, 850), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (1000, 850), (900, 850), 1)
        pygame.draw.line(gameDisplay, black, (899, 850), (899, 800), 1)

        button("Start", 150, 800, 100, 50, green, bright_green, game_loop)
        button("Quit", 900, 800, 100, 50, red, bright_red, quitgame)
        
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def game_loop():
    global pause

    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    
    x = (display_width * 0.45)
    y = (display_height * 0.6)
    x_change = 0

    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    thing_starty = -600
    thing_speed = 3
    thing_width = 100
    thing_height = 100
    dodged = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
                if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    pause = True
                    paused()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change
        gameDisplay.fill(white)

        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, black)
        thing_starty += thing_speed
        car(x,y)
        things_dodged(dodged)

        if x > display_width - car_width or x <  0:
                crash()
        if thing_starty > display_height:
            thing_starty = 0
            thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
            dodged += 1
            if thing_speed < 12:
                thing_speed += 0.5
            
        if y < thing_starty+thing_height and y + car_height > thing_starty:
            print("")
            if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x + car_width > thing_startx and x + car_width < thing_startx + thing_width:
                print("")
                crash()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(120)

game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I would imagine instead of increasing the speed of "thing", I would have to create a variable for the number of "things" and increase it by 1 every time but I'm still not sure how to do that without creating it manually (eg. 5 lines of placing 5 things on the screen randomly, instead I want it automated).

Comment: It looks like a "thing" is just a rectangle.  Have you tried simply creating a list, and appending the things to a list, processing each one in turn?  That way when a new batch is created, you can just add `number_dodged` lots of things to the list.

Answer (score 0):

create a list containing one of the objects you want to store e.g:

```
objects = [Object()]
```

Then add another object to the list wherever you increment the dodged variable:

```
if thing_starty > display_height:
    thing_starty = 0
    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)
    objects.append(Object())
    dodged += 1
```

and if you'd like to draw/blit these objects every iteration of the game loop then you can do something like this:

```
for item in objects:
    gameDisplay.blit(item, (x,y))
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm a bit confused. What is the Object in objects = [Object()]? The "thing"?

Comment: Yeah, it's one instance of it as you said you wanted to start with one when the score is zero. You then add to that list each time you increment your dodged variable.